# ORACLE Forms 12c WEBUTI_HOST call at WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE

Tags: oracleforms

I'd like to retrieve client information when initializing an Oracle Forms application. When I use `WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking('whoami')` within the `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, I encounter the following error:

> oracle.forms.webutil.host.Host bean not found. WEBUTIL HOST. Execute will not work.

However, if I call the same function later, for instance in the `WHEN-TAB-PAGE-CHANGED` trigger, it functions correctly. What would be the appropriate approach to achieve this after the application has started?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution [here](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/webutil-doesn-t-work-when-called-from-when-new-form-instanc-2066).

You have to do it with a timer. As soon as the form is initialized, the timer will fire. In the trigger `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED` you can call the `WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking('whoami')`.

So the code looks like that:

In the trigger `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` you need to create a timer, which fires 100 ms after the form is initialized and will not repeat.

```sql
declare
  timer timer;
begin
  timer := create_timer('webutil', 100, no_repeat);
end;
```

The `WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking('whoami')` call goes to `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED`.

```sql
declare
  process  WEBUTIL_HOST.PROCESS_ID;
begin
  process := WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking('whoami');
end;
```

Comment: For everyone's benefit, as a general statement, calling WebUtil from a trigger that occurs prior to form rendering (UI) should be avoided.  It is not a good practice.

The reason you get a failure is because Java Beans are not initialized until the form is rendered (or at the same time).

Comment: @MichaelJF Exactly what you're describing was my initial situation. I couldn't invoke WebUtil because it wasn't initialized. I addressed this issue with my workaround. The timer is only activated when the form is initialized, which also implies WebUtil. This logic has been running flawlessly in the production environment for weeks without any issues.